# Como crear clases para mapeado objeto/relacional?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

Soy nuevo en hibernate y jpa, tengo que crear 3 clases **User, Client y Attribute** que seran mapeadas en tablas, las clases tienen las siguientes propiedades:

1. **User** tiene: id, name, surname, password, muchos clients, muchos Attributes.
2. **Client** tiene: id, name, user (client pertenece a un usuario), muchos Attributes.
3. **Attribute** tiene id?, name, value. (**ejemplo** de un attribute de user: Name:"Numero telefonico" , Value:"333 222 111 44")

No tengo muchos problemas creando las clases user y client, pero al crear la clase **Attribute** me encuentro algo confundido, no se si crear 2 clases Attribute separadas una para los user y otra para los client o solo 1.

Por ahora lo que he hecho es esto:

**Class User:**

```
public class User {

    private String userID;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String password;
    private Set<Client> clients = new HashSet();
    private Set<UserAttribute> attributes = new HashSet();

    public User() {

    }

    /* getters and setters*/
}
```

**Class Client:**

```
public class Client {

    private String clientID;
    private String clientName;
    private User user;
    private Set<ClientAttribute> attributes = new HashSet();


    public Client() {

    }

    /* getters and setters*/
}
```

**Class UserAttribute:**

```
public class UserAttribute {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String value;
    private User user; // the owner of this attribute

    public UserAttribute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /* getters and setters*/
}
```

**Class ClientAttribute:**

```
public class ClientAttribute {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String value;
    private Client client; // the owner of this attribute

    public ClientAttribute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /* getters and setters */
    }
```

Esta bien la forma en la que e escrito las clases? Deberia usar 2 clases o solo 1 para Attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ante todo, las cuestiones de diseño no suelen tener una respuesta única y puede depender de como veas la situación; por ejemplo una opción es hacer herencia pero eso se puede complicar si luego alguien decide que, al final, los atributos de `User` y `Client` van a ser completamente diferentes.

Así que:

1. Clases separadas. No muy sofisticado, pero funciona, es simple y flexible. Puede ser algo engorroso si acaba habiendo demasiadas clases, y hay que escribir algo más.
2. Una clase con una propiedad `user` y otra `client`; según con cuál esté relacionado uno u otro de los atributos tendrá un valor. Es un poco feo, y como tienes que hacer los atributos nullables tienes que cuidar en tu lógica que no te queden filas "huérfanas" que no apunten ni a un `user` ni a un `cliente`.
3. Herencia:

   ```
   public class Attribute {

     private String id;
     private String name;
     private String value;
     // setters y getters
   }

   public class UserAttribute extends Attribute {
     private User user;
     // setters y getters
   }
   ```

   JPA permite diferentes estrategias sobre como se implementarán estas clases en tablas, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a "Herencia en JPA". Es una opción bastante popular, pero tendrás problemas si luego alguien decide que, por ejemplo, los `UserAttribute` tienen que tener un campo `id` pero los `ClientAttribute` no).

Comment: En el caso de mi proyecto, no creo que haya ese tipo de cambios ya que es solo una desktop app. Gracias por tu respuesta, tratare de implementarlo en mi proyecto.